# How to combine p-values of weighted effects?

Tags: meta-analysis, combining-p-values

Suppose I know the effect of running on strength of muscle 1 and 2 and their $p$-values. These values were calculated from the same sample. Now I want to know the effect of running on the strength of muscle 1 (weight 1) and 2 (weight 2) combined. The effect $E$ can be easily calculated:

$$E_\text{comb} = \frac{1·E_1 +2·E_2}{3}$$

How to combine the $p$ values?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just combine the $p$ values without further ado as your effects for a given subject are correlated: For example, some subject did something (besides running) during your observation period that affected their muscle 1, there is a decent chance that it also affected their muscle 2. The same thing goes for predispositions affecting muscle growth. If you would ignore this, you would be committing [pseudoreplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoreplication).

If you have a control group, the straightforward way to address this would be to compute your combined effect for all subjects in your control and treatment group and treat it like a regular observable (such as the single effects). Then compare the combined effects with an appropriate test. You wouldn’t use the $p$ values for the individual muscles. (Mind that you can easily fall into the trap of $p$ hacking here by changing your weights to minimise your $p$ value for the combined effect.)

The alternative would be to somehow establish your correlation structure and build a null model based on this, but presumably your data or prior knowledge doesn’t allow for this.